# Can't get Javascript datepicker to work

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a project for uni which involves creating a web form to book various activities in a sports hall. Part of my form involves a calendar where you can pick the day and time you would like to book your activity.

I followed a framework recommended by my lecturer from materialize.css however I have been unable to get the javascript to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        monthsFull: ['April']
        weekdaysFull: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
        today: 'Monday',
        clear: 'Remove',
        close: 'Close',
        firstDay: 1,
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        closeOnSelect: true,
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 1,
        min: new Date()
  });

    onSet: function (ele) {
   if(ele.select){
          this.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: What isn't working? Errors, wrong date, no date, etc.

Comment: Please provide full code snippets and console output/errors.

Comment: the error I get from the console is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier webberbridge.js:8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some typos (you forgot a comma at `monthsFull`) and to close a curly bracket - and, yes, the `type=text`:

Also, I could not find anything about the `onSet` function, I assumed you meant `onSelect`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    monthsFull: ['April'],
    weekdaysFull: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    today: 'Monday',
    clear: 'Remove',
    close: 'Close',
    firstDay: 1,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    closeOnSelect: true,
    selectMonths: true,
    selectYears: 1,
    min: new Date(),

  onSelect: function(ele) {
    if (ele.select) {
      this.close();
    }
  }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is big chance that reason in the input type.

Change in your HTML type of input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" />
```

If you use **type="date"**, then HTML5 will handle this tag and datepicker will not work.

Comment: This is the html I currently have is <input type="text" class="datepicker"> so if i change it then i should work is that what you're saying

Comment: sorry if I sound dumb